# adding values to an exisiting key without overwriting

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to invert a language dictionary. The problem is that there are synonyms for some words. How do I enter the synonyms without overwriting the exisiting value/s?

```
 latin_dic ={'apple': ['malum', 'pomum', 'popula'], 'fruit': ['baca', 'bacca', 'popum'], 'punishment': ['malum', 'multa']}
    new_dict={}
    for k,v in latin_dic.items():
        for item in v:
            if item in new_dict:
                new_dict[item] += k 
            else:
                new_dict[item]= k
    for k,v in sorted(new_dict.items()):
        print(k, '-', v)
```

the prblem in this dictionary of words is that malum = apple and punishment which with my effort above comes out as 'applepunishment'. I know that concatenation is wrong, but its the closest I have got. I cannot use append or rather it gives an error. I would be grateful for advice. I am trying to complete the snakify course for my own satisfaction and this is the final question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need make sure each value of the new dictionary is a list. Instead of

```
new_dict[item] = k  # the value is a string
```

you need

```
new_dict[item] = [k]  # the value is a list with the item
```

Then you can append onto that list.
Full code:

```
latin_dic ={'apple': ['malum', 'pomum', 'popula'], 'fruit': ['baca', 'bacca', 'popum'], 'punishment': ['malum', 'multa']}
new_dict={}
for k,v in latin_dic.items():
    for item in v:
        if item in new_dict:
            new_dict[item].append(k)
        else:
            new_dict[item] = [k]
for k,v in sorted(new_dict.items()):
    print(k, '-', v)
```

Comment: Thank you. For the output, the question requires the format word - translation, translation. So I still need to 'unlist' the list. Works perfectly though

Comment: There is no need to call `dict.keys()` when testing whether a key exists in a dictionary, simply use `if item in new_dict:`.

Comment: @mhawke Thank you. I changed it now. (I forgot to change it back, as I was testing whether that might have been the issue).

Answer (score 2):

You can't use append because it only works for lists. But in your new dictionary, the keys are always strings so when you write *new_dict[item] = k* you will say that the value of your new dictionary is just a string and not a list. We can fix that very easily:

```
latin_dic ={'apple': ['malum', 'pomum', 'popula'], 'fruit': ['baca', 'bacca', 'popum'], 'punishment': ['malum', 'multa']}
new_dict={}
for k,v in latin_dic.items():
  for item in v:
    if item in new_dict:
      new_dict[item].append(k)
    else:
      new_dict[item] = [k]

for k,v in sorted(new_dict.items()):
  print(k, '-', v)
```

Now we declare your new_dict values *always* as lists and you can use append.

Comment: THank you also for your suggestion. I can only 'approve' one answer though although both of you posted identical solutions. Just shows that I have not yet grasped the details and sbtilties of python! Sigh!

Comment: No problem, I'm glad we could help! Good luck learning Python!

Answer (score 2):

The fix, as others have posted, is to create a new list containing the current key when the new dictionary does not already contain a key with the associated value.

You can avoid the dictionary lookup in the `if` statement by using `dict.get()` with a default value of `[]`, like this:

```
latin_dic = {'apple': ['malum', 'pomum', 'popula'], 'fruit': ['baca', 'bacca', 'popum'], 'punishment': ['malum', 'multa']}
english_dic = {}

for k in latin_dic:
    for v in latin_dic[k]:
        english_dic[v] = english_dic.get(v, []) + [k]

for k in sorted(english_dic):
    print(k, '-', english_dic[k])
```

Alternatively, a nicer way to perform this operation is with a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

latin_dic = {'apple': ['malum', 'pomum', 'popula'], 'fruit': ['baca', 'bacca', 'popum'], 'punishment': ['malum', 'multa']}
english_dic = defaultdict(list)

for k in latin_dic:
    for v in latin_dic[k]:
        english_dic[v].append(k)

for k in sorted(english_dic):
    print(k, '-', english_dic[k])
```

Comment: Thank you. I shall study your suggestion as well. It would be best though were the output not in a list i.e. word rather than ['word']. Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: managed the output by changing print(k, '-', v) to print(k, '-',  ', '.join(v))